# -bash: ant: command not found on mac os x El Capitan

Tags: bash, apache, android-studio, ant, osx-elcapitan

I try to integrate **zxing** on my android studio project and I need **Apache Ant** for it. I followed this steps for Apache Ant install: http://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-apache-ant-on-mac-os-x/ but when I finish to follow all those steps from link, I receive this message:

> -bash: ant: command not found

Comment: *it doesn't work for me* come on! I know you can explain better. Even if this question is a perfect fit for [Apple.se]

Comment: I edited my question.:)

Comment: Thanks! What's the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mkyong/gradle/bin:/Users/mkyong/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin:/Users/mkyong/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin

Comment: it's better if you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33784290/edit) the question :) What's the output of `ls /Users/` ?

Comment: Here you have details about ls command: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ls1.html . I know what ls /../../ is doing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95459/discussion-between-thomas-and-adela).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the output of `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mkyong/gradle/bin:/Users/mky‌​ong/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin:/Users/mkyong/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin
```

It seems that you have followed the link instructions a bit too much here (step 3):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/mkyong/gradle
export M2_HOME=/Users/mkyong/apache-maven-3.1.1

# Apache Ant
export ANT_HOME=/Users/mkyong/apache-ant-1.9.4

# Export to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

Since `mkyong` refers to the [writter's](http://www.mkyong.com/author/mkyong/) username. So just do the same with *your* username (you can get it by running `whoami` in terminal) and it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now, the current version of apache is 1.9.6, this is what I modified in file.